# Coinbase php api - Scopes don't match current API version

Tags: php, coinbase-api

I am integrated coinbase php(cURL) api and I found below error. I cannot understand the meaning of this error. Please help me.

This is my php code,

```
    $COINBASE_API_KEY = '-------------';
    $COINBASE_API_SECRET = '-----------';
    $api_url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/';
    $curl = curl_init($api_url);

    $srvr_time = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/time"), true)["data"]["epoch"];
    $method="GET";
    $request="accounts";

    $Datas = $srvr_time.$method.$request;
    $hmacSig = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $Datas, base64_decode($COINBASE_API_SECRET), true));

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY: '.$COINBASE_API_KEY,
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: '. time(),
        'CB-VERSION: 2017-08-07',
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN: '.$hmacSig));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $output = json_decode($response, true);
    print_r($output);
```

Api's response is like below.

```
Array
(
    [success] => 
    [error] => Scopes don't match current API version.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'CB-VERSION: 2017-08-07'

Does this API version you're declaring match with what you've established with your app settings within Coinbase?